# Using templates as template function argument

Tags: c++

Hi everybody!
 I'm starting to learn about templates in C++, so sorry if the question is too simple =P
I'm trying to write a function like this:

```
template< template<typename> class C, typename T>
void bRedChannel(C<T> src, C<T> out)
{
    // do something
}
```

and I'm trying to call the function this way:

```
Mat_<uchar> roi = image(Rect(10, 10, rows, cols));
Mat_<uchar> masked;
bRedChannel< Mat_<uchar>, uchar >(roi, masked);
```

that results in the error

```
no matching function for call to ‘bRedChannel(cv::Mat_<unsigned char>&, cv::Mat_<unsigned char>&)´
```

What's wrong?

Update:

Here's the code as it is now:

```
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template< template<typename> class C, typename T>
void bRedChannel(C<T> src, C<T> out)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i += 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j += 2)
        {
            out(i, j) = src(i, j);
        }
    }
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  int rows = 512, cols = 512;

  Mat_<uchar> image = imread("Autumn-Desktop.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  Mat_<uchar> roi = image(Rect(10, 10, rows, cols));
  image.release();

  Mat_<uchar> masked;
  bRedChannel(roi, masked);

  namedWindow( "Result" );
  imshow( "Result", masked );

  waitKey(0);

  imwrite("teste.png", masked);

  return 0;
}
```

It runs now, but it is interrupted. The problem may be with the algorithm now, but my question was answered! Thanks @RSahu!

Comment: The correct syntax would be `bRedChannel<Mat_, uchar>(roi, masked);` but template-template parameters don't need to be used here. Have `bRedChannel` deduce its arguments instead. Or just don't use a template at all.

Comment: @0x499602D2 you're right indeed... the possibility came to my mind and I just became curious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
bRedChannel< Mat_<uchar>, uchar >(roi, masked);
            // ^^^^^^^^^
```

use

```
bRedChannel< Mat_, uchar >(roi, masked);
```

As a rule, prefer not to explicitly use the typenames when invoking a function template. The compiler should be able to deduce the typenames. Use the explicit typenames only if the compiler cannot deduce the typenames or you want to use different typenames than what the compiler deduces.

Use

```
bRedChannel(roi, masked);
```

Use the typenames explicitly only if necessary.

**Additional Feedback**

You have:

```
template< template<typename> class C, typename T>
void bRedChannel(C<T> src, C<T> out)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i += 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j += 2)
        {
            out(i, j) = src(i, j);
        }
    }
};
```

and you are using it with:

```
  Mat_<uchar> masked;
  bRedChannel(roi, masked);
```

You are modifying a local copy of `masked` in `bRedChannel`. Those modifications have no effect on `masked` in `main`. The first argument to `bRedChannel` also makes a copy of the input argument. It could be made fore efficient by changing the type to `C<T> const&`.

I would suggest changing `bRedChannel` to:

```
template< template<typename> class C, typename T>
void bRedChannel(C<T> const& src, C<T>& out)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i += 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j += 2)
        {
            out(i, j) = src(i, j);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Didn't work... now I'm getting the error "undefined reference to `void bRedChannel<cv::Mat_, unsigned char>(cv::Mat_<unsigned char>, cv::Mat_<unsigned char>)´ ". Thanks for the reply @R Sahu

Comment: I would ask this too @Praetorian =P

Comment: @Hanz0, that's an altogether different error. Is the function defined in a .h files and the .h file `#include`d in the .cpp file?

Comment: yes, it is in a .h and the file is included in the .cpp

Comment: @Hanz0, you accepted my answer. Does it mean that your problems are resolved?

Comment: </p>@RSahu, yes, your answer is right! My guess is that the problem is between me and OpenCV now =P I've updated my question with the actual code.</p> Thanks for the support and feel free to say something if it is something wrong with the code!

Comment: Perfect! I've forgot to pass by reference. Thanks a lot @RSahu! Worked perfectly!